# mysql table: decimal number default 0

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

After I typed 13,10 into the value box as shown in the image1, it comes up with     decimal(13,0). What's the problem?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Hover `?`, is `13,10` a proper format?

Comment: But why do you want decimal upto 10 digits?

Comment: just curious. It wouldn't have values, already in that column, that do not conform to that format ? i.e. larger than 1000 or more than 10 decimal places? If so than you need to adjust them before altering the table.

Comment: it's for the latitude and longitude

Comment: phpmyadmin doesn't do any processing with the values you enter, you can enter "abc" as length and sql preview will generate `...add \`lan\` decimal(abc) not null...` from that. Maybe your browser didn't send the correct values? What browser do you use, and what phpmyadmin version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be seeing the effect of [this bug](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12480), which exists with version 4.6.4 and will be fixed with the upcoming version 4.6.5. You can also apply the [patch yourself](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12480).

Comment: but i got another problem now... from the enum... 

![enum](https://s12.postimg.org/npyns29f1/Screen_Shot_2016_09_19_at_4_44_53_pm.png)

Answer (score 0):

The preview may be incorrect, but try saving it and see if that is correct.  In my testing this is working, but we may be on different versions.  Also, if it saves incorrectly (if there is a bug in phpMyAdmin) you can always do an alter (Change button) and see if that block of code handles it correctly.  If all else fails, there's always the command line to sort it out.